# Can I create a separate curve for sub-tasks in a Burndown chart?

Tags: jira, burndowncharts, greenhopper

I would like to know if it is possible to create a separate curve for sub-tasks in the Hour Burndown chart. So we will have two curves in the chart - one for the standard issue types and the other just for their sub-tasks?

Is this possible? If yes, how can I set this up?

Answer (score 0):

Answer from Matthew Cobby on [the Atlassian forums](https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Jira-Software-questions/Burndown-chart-separate-curve-for-sub-tasks/qaq-p/129359):

> You can do it via Contexts in GreenHopper which you can use to produce
> different graphs with different sets of data
>
> 1. Go to your chart board
> 2. Select the project then select the drop down to the right of the project name, it will probably say Default of On-the-fly.
> 3. Select New & you will get a popup for a new context which can be based on an existing filter (subtasks JQL: issuetype in
>    subTaskIssueTypes()) or by selecting different fields to filter by.
>    (standard issuetypes JQL: issuetype in standardIssueTypes())
> 4. Create a context based on sub-tasks only and one based on standardIssueTypes.
> 5. Look at your lovely charts based on two different sets of data.
>
> Here's the documentation: http://confluence.atlassian.com/display/GH/Using+Contexts+to+Filter+and+Highlight+Issues